# DataGrid.Measure() Manipulates Column Width

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, measure

I got a problem with the `Measure()` function of the WPF DataGrid.
If I have the `DataGridLength` on column of my `DataGrid` set to `DataGridLengthUnitType.Star`, everytime i call the `Measure()` function of the `DataGrid` all of the DataGrid´s columns width is set to around 30px. Someone got an idea why the measure function is doing this? Why is it manipulating my columns after all? Shouldn´t it just measure the size of my DataGrid?

edit: After setting the `CanContentScroll` Property auf my `ScrollContentPresenter` to `false` it works fine, but that extremly slows my `datagrid` down. Some suggestions?:)

edit2: My columns are created via a `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter`

Answer (score 0):

The UIElement.Measure() method updates the DesiredSize property of the control according to the value of the *availableSize* parameter. The value you're setting might be smaller than you wish. I'd try to set a big value to see what happens.

Comment: btw the size of the grid remains the same!!! Just the width of the columns changes